# Pseudo-Class:focus-within does not work correctly

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class

I use the **pseudo-class:focus-within** on my menu to show the sub-menu on click, but it shows it for a second, and then the sub-menu disappears.
There is no problem when I use pseudo-class: hover, I just have the problem with focus-within.

> **li class="has-sub-menu"** when I click on it to show the **ul class="sub-menu"** it get disappear.

Can anybody help me, please?

**here are my HTML and CSS codes.**

```css
li.has-sub-menu{
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;    
}

ul.sub-menu{
    position: absolute;
    top:20px ;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 3px #a1a1a1;
    border-radius:2%;
    border: 1px solid; 
    display: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    min-width: 100px;
}

li.has-sub-menu:focus-within ul.sub-menu{
    display: block;
}

.sub-menu li{
    border-bottom:1px #a1a1a1 dashed;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <ul>
        <li class="has-sub-menu">
            <ul class="sub-menu">

                <li><a href="">VGA</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Power</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Case</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Network </a></li>
                <li><a href="">CPU</a></li>
                <li><a href="">CPU FAN</a></li>

            </ul><a href="">products</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I ran the demo and couldn't figure out what exactly are you talking about. What exactly should I hover/focus?

Comment: what browser do you use?

Comment: @TJ The one with the down arrow next to it. I use Chrome.

Comment: Your HTML has so many errors including fatal ones. Put in in an HTML validator and fix them...

Comment: @TJ I did it now, but it didn't solve the problem

Comment: @TJ I edited the HTML codes in the post.

Comment: The post isn't edited at all...

Comment: @TJ You are right, I checked it and edited it again,  I checked my codes by HTML validator and solved the errors, there is no error on my HTML codes now.

Comment: Can you create a [link]https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example I'm finding it difficult to see what is happening given there are several sub menus. Could you put up an example which shows the problem but with just one?

Comment: @AHaworth I'm very grateful for your help. I minimized my codes and edited them in my post. Could you please check them now?

Comment: Thanks for the minimized snippet. I think I found the problem and have put up an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code uses anchor tag elements so as to have a focusable element within the li elements.

The problem with this, alongside the empty href attribute, is that it focuses (so we see the sub menu) but then immediately moves to the link (which is empty) and unfocuses. So we see a flash of the sub menu then it disappears.

So what can we do to put a focusable element into the li element?

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) has this advice:

> **onclick events** Anchor elements are often abused as fake buttons by
> setting their href to # or javascript:void(0) to prevent the page from
> refreshing, then listening for their click events .
>
> These bogus href values cause unexpected behavior when
> copying/dragging links, opening links in a new tab/window,
> bookmarking, or when JavaScript is loading, errors, or is disabled.
> They also convey incorrect semantics to assistive technologies, like
> screen readers.
>
> Use a `button` instead. In general, you should only use a hyperlink
> for navigation to a real URL.

So this snippet uses the code given in the question, changing the a elements for buttons, and removing the background-color and border from the button styling.

```css
li.has-sub-menu {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

ul.sub-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 3px #a1a1a1;
  border-radius: 2%;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  min-width: 100px;
}

li.has-sub-menu:focus-within ul.sub-menu {
  display: block;
}

.sub-menu li {
  border-bottom: 1px #a1a1a1 dashed;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  position: relative;
}

.has-sub-menu button {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="has-sub-menu">
    <ul class="sub-menu">

      <li><a href="">VGA</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Power</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Case</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Network </a></li>
      <li><a href="">CPU</a></li>
      <li><a href="">CPU FAN</a></li>

    </ul><button>products</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```